# Need help resolving the paradox of limits in proof of differentiability implies continuity.

Tags: calculus

I have been following Professor David Jerison’s 18.01, Single Variable Calculus on MIT OCW. In Lecture 2 (https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01-single-variable-calculus-fall-2006/video-lectures/lecture-2-limits/), he outlines the proof for “differentiability implies continuity”.

Proof: [http://www-math.mit.edu/~djk/18_01/chapter02/proof04.html](http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Edjk/18_01/chapter02/proof04.html)

Now, he mentions that we are multiplying and dividing by $x-x_{0}$ which should be $0/0$ and is not a logically permitted operation. Then he goes on to mention that it is permitted in this case as technically the limit is not $0$ but a very small number.

But in the next step we substitute $lim_{x->x_{0}} x-x_{0} = 0$.

**My question is: Doesn’t this mean that $x=x_{0}$? The way this entire paradox seems to have been resolved relies on some sort of arbitrary loophole that was constructed when we ran into a problem and then immediately contradicted in the very next step. I find this throughout calculus and I'm unsure how best to resolve it.**

I watched 3blue1brown's video about the Paradox of the Derivative (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9vKqVkMQHKk). Grant concludes that a derivative should be thought of as the best constant constant approximation for an infinitesimal change.

Does that mean $lim_{x->x_{0}} x-x_{0} \approx 0$ and essentially, limits and derivatives everywhere should be replaced with $\approx$ instead of $=$? That is the only way it kinda seems to make any sense to me.

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: After the formula $\lim_{x\to x_0}x-x_0=0$, you ask "Doesn't this mean that $x=x_0$?" No it does not. The only way I can see to get from $\lim_{x\to x_0}x-x_0=0$ to $x=x_0$ is to simply erase $\lim_{x\to x_0}$, and erasing part of a statement is not a correct form of reasoning.

Comment: There is a subtle point in the definition of limit that you may have missed: $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} f(x) = L$ means that : for all $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $0 < d(x, c) < \delta$, $0 < d(f(x), L) < \epsilon$.

Note that there is a condition that $0 < d(x, c) $, so $x \neq c$.